# Cassandra CQLSH not starting after computer restart

Tags: cassandra

Yestarday, I have `datastax cqlsh` working fine. I have created `keyspaces` and `tables` into it.

But today it is not starting. It says `cannot connect to localhost:9160 Connection refused`.
I am on windows 7 machine.

Any idea?

Comment: Have you configured the service to run at start up?

Comment: yes.. its automatic only...

Answer (score 0):

In `cassandra.yaml` you need to set the RPC address to accept connections on any interface:

```
rpc_address: 0.0.0.0
```

Also make sure the Windows firewall does not block 9160. By default it blocks inbound connections to the IP address assigned to your machine, though it does not block localhost/127.0.0.1.